# get return value from 2 threads in C

Tags: c, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct tmp_num{
    int tmp_1;
    int tmp_2;
}t_num;

t_num t_nums;

void *num_mezzo_1(void *num_orig);
void *num_mezzo_2(void *num_orig);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int tmp=0,rc1,rc2,num;

    num=atoi(argv[1]);
    if(num <= 3){
        printf("Questo è un numero primo: %d\n", num);
        exit(0);
    }

    if( (rc1=pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &num_mezzo_1, (void *)&num)) ){
        printf("Creazione del thread fallita: %d\n", rc1);
        exit(1);
    }
    if( (rc2=pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &num_mezzo_2, (void *)&num)) ){
            printf("Creazione del thread fallita: %d\n", rc2);
            exit(1);
    }

    t_nums.tmp_1 = 0;
    t_nums.tmp_2 = 0;
    pthread_join(thread1, (void **)(&t_nums.tmp_1));
    pthread_join(thread2, (void **)(&t_nums.tmp_2));
    tmp=t_nums.tmp_1+t_nums.tmp_2;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", tmp, t_nums.tmp_1, t_nums.tmp_2);
    if(tmp>2){
        printf("Questo NON è un numero primo: %d\n", num);
    }
    else{
        printf("Questo è un numero primo: %d\n", num);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void *num_mezzo_1(void *num_orig){
    int cont_1;
    int *n_orig=(int *)num_orig;
    t_nums.tmp_1 = 0;
    for(cont_1=1; cont_1<=(*n_orig/2); cont_1++){
        if((*n_orig % cont_1) == 0){
            (t_nums.tmp_1)++;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)(&t_nums.tmp_1));
    return NULL;
}

void *num_mezzo_2(void *num_orig){
    int cont_2;
    int *n_orig=(int *)num_orig;
    t_nums.tmp_2 = 0;
    for(cont_2=((*n_orig/2)+1); cont_2<=*n_orig; cont_2++){
        if((*n_orig % cont_2) == 0){
            (t_nums.tmp_2)++;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)(&t_nums.tmp_2));
    return NULL;
}
```

How this program works: i have to input a number and this program will calculate if it is a prime number or not (i know that it is a bad algorithm but i only need to learn *pthread*).
The problem is that the returned values are too much big.
For example if i write "12" the value of `tmp tmp_1 tmp_2` into the main are `12590412 6295204 6295208`.
Why i got those numbers??

Comment: My first reaction is that this code is not thread safe, since you are updating the same variable from two different threads. But after taking a closer look, it seems that you keep the 2 members separate. Is there any logical reason why they must be in the same struct though? It seems like completely redundant obfuscation to me. You could make the program so much better and cleaner if the threads just work on one int variable each. Merge them together once the threads are done, if needed.

Comment: you can try and reread my answer from your last question, it solves part of your problem

Comment: @Minion91 in fact i've changed my program to meet your answer :) i've changed the variable from local to global (i'm lazy) so i haven't to malloc anything...am i right???

Comment: @polslinux no, you just circumvented part of your problem

Comment: Initialize `tmp_1` and `tmp_2` *before* you call `pthread_create()`.  Right now you spawn threads writing to those members, and then in the main thread zero them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your return statements:

First:

```
pthread_exit((void *)(&t_nums.tmp_1));
return NULL; 
}
```

If you're going to just return and die, you don't need to call pthread_exit()

Second, you're returning an address (&), so that's what you're printing. Try this:

```
return ((void *)(t_nums.tmp_1)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some considerations:

1. Remember that the return value from `pthread_exit` only works for JOINABLE threads. In some other situations you may use a different pthread type (detached).
2. In your example you were returning something like this: void pthread_exit(**void **retval**);
3. There is a sigsegv when there is no args.